# Simplest way to create MVC model class from entity db class

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a DB layer with mit entity classes and want to quickly create matching mvc models.

e.g. 
DB : Album Enittiy Class

MVC:

- CreateAlbumModel
- EditAlbumModel
- PublishAlbumModel

How can I automate this process so that I don't need to start from scratch for each MVC model class?

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to automate things in visual studio, for example take a look at

- T4 templates
- Visual studio macros - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b4c73967%28v=vs.80%29.aspx
- hardcore stuff : Guidance Automation Extensions - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff709808.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Personally, codesmith has worked well for us. The T4 templates will regenerate with every single compile. So unless you want to use partial classes for any code that won't change, then you must be careful not to add any code that will be deleted upon the next compile.

If you are generating these from your current model using the .tt templates, then you are already taking this approach of recreating upon every compile.